# How to judge whether the item has been recycled in listview when using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am following the article from developer.android.com
["Making ListView Scrolling Smooth"](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

The snippet of the code is:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) { 
    super.onPostExecute(result); 
    if (v.position == position) { 
        // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the 
        // progress and set and show the image 
        v.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        v.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        v.icon.setImageBitmap(result); 
    } 
}
```

I do not understand what the variable "position" is. And why "v.position == position" can judge whether the item hasn't been recycled or not.

I tried the idea: set a class variable position is equal to the position in getView. But it doesn't work.

And I also find a similary code to do async task in 
"[Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)",
it use "WeakReference" to judge whether the item exists or not.
Are the both ways equally effective?

Answer (score 1):

When the Adapter recycles a view, the position changes. This happens automatically by the framework and you won't know it happened until after you check the value. The custom ViewHolder object that was set the last time the view was handed to getView() will still be there, so it's a handy place to track what the position was when work started. If they don't match, the View has been recycled, so you shouldn't set the bitmap since it's the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks. So I should set a class variable mPosition. let mPosition = position in getView(). Let viewHolder.position = position in getView(). And in onPostExecute, I will check viewHolder.position == mPosition. However, this does not work. Please tell me my above logic is wrong.

Comment: There are 4 items in my listview. Only the last item shows the icon. Actually I think mPosition changes when the adapter access items one by one. So when the 4 items are in the listview, the first item is still doing async task, but the getView navigates to the second item.

Comment: Are you creating a new ViewHolder object for every call to getView() or are you re-using the same one every time across multiple views?

Comment: ViewHolder is created in getView. And if I comment out the sentence of judgement "viewHolder.position == position", it works well, which means the members in the viewHolder object are pointing to the correct objects.

Comment: Make sure you *don't* create a new ViewHolder _every_ time. You only need a new ViewHolder for new (non-recycled) Views.